# IE opens a new window for a link, FF doesn't

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Very strange, I have a list of products.  When a user clicks on an the image it opens up a new IE window.

Firefox doesn't do this.

What could be the reason for this?

the urls are:

```
http://website.example.com
```

and clicking on the image goes to (which is hosted on another server):

```
http://store.website.example.com
```

Could this be some internal security measure or ?

Note:  I don't have target=_blank and I even tried addign target=_self but no change.

Update
It turns out some javascript function was searching for certain urls and modifying its behaviour! thanks.

Comment: In FF does it open in the same tab, or in a different tab? There's a setting to open new windows in a new tab instead.

Comment: You have to show us how you're creating and presenting the link.  Is it in a link tag?  Are you doing some strange thing with JavaScript?  Are you using some framework?

Answer (score 3):

A new window is generally prompted by a target attribute on the A tag:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">linktext</a>
```

FF can supress/override this behaviour in it's preferences.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://store.website.example.com" target="_blank">
```